# Django: How to use modal as a form to update an object

Tags: django, django-forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use modal as a edit form but I don't know good way.

Currently my `views.py` is like this.

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_pk):

    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_pk)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, user=request.user)
    else:
       form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

and I have a template for this view.

What I want to do is
from the page that lists a bunch of entry objects, the edit form for the object is shown when I click edit button.

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    ...
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEntryModal">Edit</button>

    <!-- modal for the object -->
```

Anyone who could give me tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send back your form as html and stick it in the modal before you show it. so on click, you would first do you ajax request, and this will send back your form as html. For example,

```
def edit_entry(request, entry_pk):
   ....
   entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_pk)

   if request.method != 'POST':
       form = EntryForm(instance=entry, user=request.user)
       return HttpResponse(form.as_p())   # This will return the plain html of a form
   ....
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar task and first created an ajax request from the template to load the data:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  });
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(event){
    var modal = $(this)
    var pk = $(this).data('pid')
    $.ajax({
        data: {'pk': pk},
        url: "{% url 'search:load_paper' %}",
        context: document.body,
        error: function(response, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        modal.html(response);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The `load_paper` function looks like the following:

```
def load_paper(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    object = get_object_or_404(Paper, pk = pk)
    form = PaperForm(instance=object)
    return render(request, 'edit_paper_modal.html', {
        'object': object,
        'pk': pk,
        'form': form,
        })
```

The data is rendered in the 'edit_paper_modal.html',  which looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <form action="{% url 'search:edit_paper' pk=object.pk %}" method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Paper</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{form|crispy}}
              {{ form.media }}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes" />
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
</div>
```

The key thing here is that I am passing the `pk` of the paper back to the `edit_paper` function in `views.py` which actually saves the form.
Hope this is useful!

Comment: Where do you place your script, In edit_paper_modal.html? Or is the script in a differnt html where you list your items?

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to possible only with django template. 
you need js or jquery or any frontend framework .

when you click edit button A edit from will appeared in current dom and you need to make ajax call to get initial data for edit from. the edit the data and submit the data vai ajax and in backend update the object. django rest framework is more suitable for this kind of task.